# MySQL - how to select query values which doesn't have a specific data

Tags: mysql, select

I'm having some troubles (thinking about it) doing a select from this table.

**tb_details**:

```
id            status             det_id
1               5                  22  
2               1                  22
3               0                  22
4               5                  25
5               1                  25
6               5                  27
7               1                  27
8               5                  32
9               1                  32
10              0                  32
```

How can i make a select query to show **just the `det_id` values which doesn't have a `0` in the table**, maybe something like this:

```
det_id
  25
  27
```

Comment: When you say **a 0 in the table**, are you talking about a 0 in `status`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach (out of several workable approaches) is to use an anti-join pattern.

```
SELECT t.det_id
  FROM this_table t
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT r.det_id
           FROM this_table r
          WHERE r.status = 0
          GROUP BY r.det_id
       ) s
    ON s.det_id = t.det_id
 WHERE s.det_id IS NULL
 GROUP BY t.det_id
```

Let's unpack that a bit.

The inline view (aliased as **`s`**) returns a distinct list of `det_id` values for which a `status=0` row does exist in `this_table`.

The `LEFT JOIN` operation returns all `det_id` values from `this_table` **`t`**, along with the matching `det_id` from **`s`**. If a match is not found, the "left outerness" of the join means that all rows from **`t`** will be returned, whether a match is found or not.

The "trick" is the predicate in the `WHERE` clause, testing whether the value of the column returned from **`s`** is NULL or not. The predicate effectively excludes any rows from **`t`** which had a matching row found in **`s`**.

So, all that remains to return is rows from **`t`** that didn't have a match in **`s`**.

We add a `GROUP BY t.det_id` (or we could add the `DISTINCT` keyword), to return a list of distinct `det_id` values.

---

This isn't the only approach. You could also use a `NOT EXISTS` predicate ...

```
SELECT t.det_id
  FROM this_table t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM this_table r
          WHERE r.det_id = t.det_id
            AND r.status = 0
       )
 GROUP BY t.det_id
```

(This differs slightly, in that a row with a NULL value for `det_id` could be returned, where the previous query would not return it. That first query could be tweaked to make it return the same result as this.)

You could also use a `NOT IN`, taking care that the subquery does *not* return any NULL values for `det_id`.

```
SELECT t.det_id
  FROM this_table t
 WHERE t.det_id NOT IN
       ( SELECT r.det_id
           FROM this_table r
          WHERE r.status = 0
            AND r.det_id IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY r.det_id
       )
 GROUP BY t.det_id
```

There are several statements what will return the specified resultset.

Answer (score 1):

Another and simpler way of doing this is:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT det_id FROM TB
WHERE det_id NOT IN
(SELECT det_id RFOM TB WHERE status = 0);
```

Comment: +1. This query returns the result specified by OP for the sample data, and as long as we have a guarantee that NONE of the `status=0` rows in TB have a NULL value in the `det_id` column. For the more general case, where we don't have that guarantee, we'd want to include a predicate in the subquery that ensures that NULL value of `det_id` is _never_ returned, e.g. `AND det_id IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to only have the det_id where no other colum is 0 you should write

```
SELECT det_id FROM TABLE WHERE
 Col1 <> 0
AND
 Col2 <> 0
```

and so on...

If you want only 1 result per type add

```
GROUP BY det_id
```

at the end of the query.

Comment: The query in this answer doesn't achieve the result OP specified (per my understanding of the specification.)